# Stripe customer-based email receipt

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe appears to allow account-wide payment receipt emails[1,2], and charge-specific payment receipt overrides [2,3]. This means that either every customer can get emails for every billing, or that we can hand pick which charges generate an email receipt.

Does Stripe allow per-customer or per-subscription payment emails, such that certain customers can receive email receipts for every recurring charge, and other customers never receive receipts?

Sources:

[1] https://stripe.com/blog/email-receipts

[2] https://support.stripe.com/questions/email-receipts

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reaching out to Stripe's support directly, they informed me that they do not offer an in-house solution to the question I posed. Instead they suggested I look at third party integrations. They offered the following links:

- https://www.sendwithus.com/stripe
- https://stripe.com/docs/integrations#email-marketing-dunning